# explanation of value in multiprocessing? (unexpected output)

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have this code here:

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Process

def func(x):
    x.value += 1
    print("child process - " + str(x.value))


x = Value("i")
x.value = 0
print("main process - " + str(x.value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=func, args=(x, ))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p1.close()

print("end - " + str(x.value))
```

Now, I would expect the output of this code to be:

```
main process - 0
child process - 1
end - 1
```

But instead I am getting:

```
main process - 0
main process - 0
end - 0
child process - 1
end - 1
```

Can someone explain this to me? I'm new to multiprocessing so I'm probably doing something wrong.
Regards

Comment: anything not in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guards will be executed 2x

Comment: Thank you, I just put everything under `if __name__ == "__main__":` then and it should all work?

Comment: all the prints at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that solution suggested by Joran Beasley works.
When you put everything under `if __name__ == "__main__"` it works just like it should